# CNES report throws error "{"errors":[{"msg":"An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator"}]}"

Tags: sonarqube

I have sonarqube 7.1 and sonar-scanner-cli-3.0.2.768 installed. I have added the sonar-cnes-report.jar in the sonarqube plugins folder. After running the sonar-scanner it creates a folder "scanner-report" in root directory but it doesnot have any proper report except some pb files.

In the sonarqube web, if I select the project in the "cnes report" menu, it throws error

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: any solution or guidance? It will be really appreciated.

Comment: Base on the Compatibility matrix [here](https://github.com/lequal/sonar-cnes-report) it should work. Did you see any relevant errors in the SonarQube log? It doesn't hurt to post an issue on the plugin creators page. Try also to use the latest plugin (3.0.1) posted 3 days ago.